# Does accessing @_ directly avoid a memory copy of a large scalar?

Tags: perl

So while attempting to patch a bug recently, a fellow hacker told me that since the value of the string passed to the subroutine (method) might be quite large,  accessing it via `$_[1]` would avoid the memory copy. However, I thought that any value passed to a subroutine was copied to `@_` in the first place? so in the below example is the memory copied twice? or am I wrong about the copy made when passing to the method?

```
sub foo {
    my $self = shift

    $_[0]    # access $str in @_ directly
    my ( $str ) = @_; # makes another copy of @_
}

sub bar {
    my $self = shift;
    my $str = 'something very large'; 

    $self->foo( $str ); #copies $str to the @_ of foo
}
```

This is why I suggested to the author allowing pass by a scalar ref, which will avoid a copy (other than the reference itself ) when passing to the method itself. To reiterate: does passing a value to a subroutine mean the value gets copied into `@_`?

Comment: One thing to remember: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: @eugeney thanks but understanding how things work is not

Comment: @eugeney So then we can create a special path in `sqrt(evil)` that returns `Premature optimization` immediately, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html (emphasis is mine):

> Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_` . Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` . **The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters.** In particular, if an element `$_[0]` is updated, the corresponding argument is updated (or an error occurs if it is not updatable). If an argument is an array or hash element which did not exist when the function was called, that element is created only when (and if) it is modified or a reference to it is taken. (Some earlier versions of Perl created the element whether or not the element was assigned to.) Assigning to the whole array `@_` removes that aliasing, and does not update any arguments.

By my reading, this seems to indicate that, by default, no copy occurs into `@_`.

Though I will admit that the language used is a little obtuse.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, elements in `@_` are aliased.  No copy occurs passing arguments into subroutines.

This means you can do useful but surprising things like:

```
sub strip {
    $_[0] =~ s{^\s+}{};
    $_[0] =~ s{\s+$}{};
}

my $var = "   foo   ";
strip($var);
print $var;    # "foo"
```

Such action at a distance is typically surprising and dangerous.  There's no indication to the user that `strip` will modify its arguments.  A safer and more obvious thing to do is to pass the value in as a reference.

```
sub strip {
    my $ref = shift;
    $$ref =~ s{^\s+}{};
    $$ref =~ s{\s+$}{};
}

my $var = "   foo   ";
strip(\$var);
print $var;    # "foo"
```

This both saves memory (only the reference is copied), lets you name the argument inside the subroutine, and since they must pass a reference it lets the caller know their variable may be modified.

An alternative is to use a *read-only alias*.  This gives you the memory optimization of not copying the variable, allows you to name the variable, but prevents you from accidentally changing it.

There's several ways to achieve this, but [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/module/Method::Signatures) makes it convenient.

```
use Method::Signatures;

func no_copy($string is alias is ro) {
    # $string is an alias to $var
    print "$string\n";

    # But it cannot be altered because $string is read-only.
    # This will throw an error.
    $string .= "bar";
}

my $var = "foo";
no_copy($var);
```

Answer (score 2):

No copy occurs for `$_[0]` that wouldn't occur for `$str` since they're two different names for the same variable.

```
$ perl -E'my $str; sub { say \$str == \$_[0] ?1:0 }->( $str );'
1
```

It's the assignment that makes the copy in `my ( $str ) = @_;`.